# MPLS over GRE tunnel with Linux iproute2

Tags: linux, mpls, tunnel, gre

I'm trying to encapsulate IP packets in MPLS, transported over a GRE tunnel between two Linux hosts (a and b). a has `10.199.0.1` on GRE tunnel interface `foo4`, while b has `10.199.0.2` on GRE tunnel interface `foo4`. I'm able to ping each other with the the following route:

```
10.199.0.0/24 dev foo4
```

on both a and b.

Now I want to encapsulate the packets that go through the tunnel with MPLS. I'm doing the following on a:

```
ip route change 10.199.0.0/24 encap mpls 100 dev foo4
```

... which encapsulates the packets from a that go into `10.199.0.0/24` according to my understanding. And the following on b to decapsulate the packet:

```
ip -f mpls 100 dev lo
```

... which decapsulates the packet and sends it to the local loopback for further routing.

With the above setting, a and b are both able to ping each other.

Then I'm applying the same strategy to b:

On b:

```
ip route change 10.199.0.0/24 encap mpls 101 dev foo4
```

On a:

```
ip -f mpls 101 dev lo
```

Yet it's not working. When I ping b from a, I get the following capture on a:

```
tcpdump: listening on foo4, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
14:47:50.888846 Out ethertype MPLS unicast (0x8847), length 104: MPLS (label 100, exp 0, [S], ttl 64)
        (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 16234, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.199.0.1 > 10.199.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 21604, seq 1, length 64
14:47:50.894911  In ethertype MPLS unicast (0x8847), length 104: MPLS (label 101, exp 0, [S], ttl 64)
        (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 49128, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.199.0.2 > 10.199.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 21604, seq 1, length 64
```

... and the following capture on b:

```
tcpdump: listening on foo4, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
14:51:03.544222  In ethertype MPLS unicast (0x8847), length 104: MPLS (label 100, exp 0, [S], ttl 64)
        (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56858, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.199.0.1 > 10.199.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 27962, seq 1, length 64
14:51:03.544393 Out ethertype MPLS unicast (0x8847), length 104: MPLS (label 101, exp 0, [S], ttl 64)
        (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 54680, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.199.0.2 > 10.199.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 27962, seq 1, length 64
```

The packet reply packet has been received, yet ping didn't say that it received the packet (i.e. no reply on ping's stdout).

When I ping a from b, however, a did not make a reply. tcpdump on a:

```
15:15:13.594917  In ethertype MPLS unicast (0x8847), length 104: MPLS (label 101, exp 0, [S], ttl 64)
        (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52653, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.199.0.2 > 10.199.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 47152, seq 2, length 64
```

tcpdump on b:

```
15:17:08.450994 Out ethertype MPLS unicast (0x8847), length 104: MPLS (label 101, exp 0, [S], ttl 64)
        (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52944, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.199.0.2 > 10.199.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 49211, seq 1, length 64
```

*(the captures above are not performed in the same time; please ignore the difference in echo id's, sequence numbers and times)*

My questions are as follows:

- why when pinging b from a, ping reports that no reply has been received, despite the fact that echo replies are actually received?
- why a won't respond to b's echo requests?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I forgot to accept mpls input as well as to turn of `rp_filter` on machine a. Doing the following worked out the problem:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
sysctl -w net.mpls.conf.foo4.input=1
```